# Significance of 'T' in Booker T Washington

Tags: meaning-in-context

At 1 hr 52 mins into [this](http://www.c-span.org/video/?71350-1/plessy-v-ferguson-reargument), Judge Louis Pollak says:

> Do I write that his [Booker T Washington's] middle initial T. stood for 'Tom'?

This is then followed by not simply laughter, but gasps of horror? Would someone please explain the deeper, more subtle English implications? I know that his actual middle name isn't Tom, but I don't apprehend the uproar?

Comment: [Uncle Tom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom#Epithet)

Comment: @snailboat - why didn't you post that as an answer? (I have the sneaking suspicion you are being selfless, allowing others to get the rep, right?) :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @snailboat mentioned in the comments, ["Uncle Tom"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom#Epithet) is an epithet that is particularly offensive when referring to a black person. Making a joke about it, especially when talking about someone as well respected as Booker T. Washington, would probably not go over well with at least part of the audience.

And I'm marking this as a community wiki, so I'm not [making a grab](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/grab_18) for reputation by [riding on @snailboat's coat tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_coattails) :)

Answer (score -1):

First, the correct format would be Booker T. Washington

Second, there are a few reasons his initial would be included (I'm not sure as to which applies specifically to him.) This list is most likely not exhaustive, and also applies to people who use any means other than first name and surname.

A. The initial is sometimes included to distinguish one person from another with the same name. This can be by choice. For example, actor Michael J. Fox includes his initials because at the time he started acting there was another actor named Michael Fox. This can also just be a practice used by others. Former President George W. Bush's middle initial is often used when specifying him to distinguish him from his father, former President George H. W. Bush.

B. The initial is also often included when the individual's last name is common. There are a lot of Washingtons, I'm not sure how many Bookers there are, but it could essentially be "preemptive."

C. Some people just prefer to have their name referenced in a particular way. If they are published, they will often be referred to by whatever name they have chosen to publish under, such as W. E. B. Du Bois.

Third, not important, but his middle name was "Taliaferro"

I personally go by Gregory B. Miller when I sign things, as my name is quite common otherwise.

Comment: It's noteworthy that [Michael J. Fox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_J._Fox) did _not_ include "his" initials. His Name was Michael _Andrew_ Fox. The _J_ had no meaning other than the distinction from the existing Michael Fox. And if I am not mistaken, the younger one had little choice in the matter; Hollywood would not cast him as Michael Fox, so he had to change his name.